# How run main class or tests in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I upgraded my IntelliJ IDEA from 2017 to 2018.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) and can't find `run` button when want to tests or main class.

[image]

and can't run from tests

[image]

How run main class or tests in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1?

Comment: have you tried "main menu | file | invalidate caches"

Comment: @Jocke  yes, it is my first step :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the IntelliJ IDEA using automatic updates. Most likely an error occurred.

Cured with forced removal and a new installation. Imported previous settings.jar
All work fine.